# How to change Tkinter icon without adding a path

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I want to change the tkinter default icon permanently, without adding a path for the new ico file, so if i send the script to another person he could use it with the new icon..
Is it possible?

Comment: i dont think thats possible, you have to include the icon file too, while sending

Answer (score 1):

While making .exe file you can use

```
pyinstaller -w --onefile --icon=app.ico app.py
```

this above command then while sharing also it has app.icon(mean which icon you give that will remain) in your application.

Comment: I am using Auto py to exe program to create the exe file, tried some options there but without success...